# Altium part has hidden rectangles causing it to overlap other components

Tags: altium

I downloaded an Eagle LBR file of an RP2040 WIO and imported it into Altium. When adding it to my PCB, I cannot fully move the component into the corner as it thinks its footprint is bigger than it actually is. When I drop it, it shifts the component over 900mil. I also cant move it close to other components as it seems to have a 900mill outline around the actual part where nothing else can be.

https://media1.giphy.com/media/mi8I7ZXkayUzYhssE5/giphy.gif?cid=790b761141f2c228d9a9798b881b61850718a09a6bde17ff&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g

[image]

If I edit the pcblib and use CTL-A to select all I can see there are some gray rectangles where I'm guessing a label would be.

How to select and delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pads are selected by Ctrl-A, you should see them in the PCB Panel. Try manually finding them there and then deleting them.

Although, you should be able to place components beyond the origin point no matter if they have hidden parts or not. Try to move your board outline further in and up, redefine the origin point to your new outline, and then align the component how you want it.

Which Altium-version are you running? Earlier Altium-versions had an "absolute origin" in the bottom left, nothing was able to be placed beyond it, but if you moved the origin point in and then defined your board from that, you could have components on all sides of the origin. This is no longer an issue in recent versions in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the PCB panel. What I ended up doing is Ctrl-A and manually deselected everything I wanted to keep. Would have been faster through the PCB panel and is good info to have for the future. Thanks!